# UIWebView can not show .docx diagram properly?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, docx

I had a problem to display .docx file in UIWebView. It is not showing digram properly. It looks stretched and mixed with other text file.
I am using below code to display .docx file.

```
         NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"File Name"];
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open & view view .doc, .docx, .rtf, .ppt, .pptx, .xlsx, .xls file in iphone using UIWebview in Document directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953584/how-to-open-view-view-doc-docx-rtf-ppt-pptx-xlsx-xls-file-in-ipho)

Answer (score 1):

Opening a web view may cause Word files to look distorted. Its similar to when certain word files look distorted when opened in Pages application.

The web view may not be able to exactly render the doc file the way it was created and you cannot do anything about it.

You may want to look at the QuickLook Framework for iOS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html

It supports the following formats:

iWork documents
Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)
Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
PDF files
Images
Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type (see * Uniform Type Identifiers Reference) 
Comma-separated value (csv) files

More specifically you may want to look at the QLPreviewController: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController

Comment: It seems that whatever rendering issue are present in the web view are also the same in the QLPreviewController so no luck there